# Trying to create a new column in pandas with 1 if greater than or 0 otherwise.

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a conditional statement in pandas using the lambda properties. I think maybe my syntax is a bit off and I need a little course correction. Any advice would be appreciated:

```
import pandas as pd

Top15['HighRenew'] = Top15['% Renewable'].map(lambda x: 1 if Top15[(Top15['% Renewable'] >= Top15['% Renewable'].median())] else 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by casting the boolean series to int:

```
Top15['HighRenew'] = (Top15['% Renewable'] >= Top15['% Renewable'].median()).astype(int)
```

Comment: Wrong number of items passed 22, placement implies 1

Comment: sorry but this returns a series of ints 1/0 your error implies you only have a single row which is different to your original intention so you'll need to post sample data, your code, my code and the errors produced from it

Comment: I figured out another way. I just applied this `Top15['HighRenew'] = np.where(Top15['% Renewable'] >= Top15['% Renewable'].median(), int(1), Top15['% Renewable'])` and it seemed to get what i wanted. However , this might not be a quick way to do this.

Comment: that should be quick but what i suggested should've worked

Answer (score 0):

You can use map but your lambda function is incorrect - there's nowhere for map to put the variable.

You need:

```py
map(lambda x: 1 if (x >= Top15['% Renewable'].median()) else 0)
```